# Tensorflow Eager Execution on Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, eager

I'm trying to enable eager execution with Tensorflow on a Colab notebook but I get an error message:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

> *ValueError: tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup*

I tried to click "reset runtime" in order to run tf.enable_eager_execution at startup but the error rises again.

Opening a different notebook didn't help.

What can I do in Colab in order to allow eager execution after this error rises?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug on our side, fix is now live, and the original code snippet should be working again. See [Tensorflow eager mode dose not work when GPU is enabled in google colab · Issue #262 · googlecolab/colabtools](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/262).

(NB: I'm on the Google Colaboratory team.)